# Filter chatter visibility on case records in customer community

Tags: case, chatter, customer-community

Support staff have been using chatter to communicate internally on case records. We want to launch a customer community that will allow customer community users to create cases and view existing cases they created. The default layout comes with a chatter feed sidebar component that lets customers post to chatter to make a comment on their open cases. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to filter which comments they can see. We'd like customer community users to be able to post a comment and communicate with support staff, but also let staff communicate with each other internally without those comments being exposed to the public feed. Is there a way to filter which chatter posts are visible to community login users?

Comment: Don't think chatter is a good solution for this, Case comments can be used to allow external users to interact with internal users.

Comment: @Raul maybe i'm misunderstanding what this component does. this is in the sidebar of the default case detail layout inside the community. is this a feed of case comments and not chatter? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujj0c9iv16k8rnh/Screen%20Shot%202020-06-30%20at%203.42.56%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @Raul can case comments be filtered to limit which comments are visible to external users?

Comment: Sorry my bad I was not clear enough. The case feed having post and comments is part of chatter (I think), there is no way to control the visibility of feed, a user having access to case record can see the feed. There is a [case comments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_comments_create_detail_page.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) functionality that is specifically used for this purpose.

Comment: yes case comments has a public checkbox when enabled by internal user while adding comment; makes it visible to external users. And all comments added by external use is public by default.